# The system and ALSA mixer both recognize my sound cards but still, no sound

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, amd-graphics

I have followed the [SoundTroubleShootingGuide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingGuide#Appendix_B_.28Using_AlsaMixer.29). The system and ALSA mixer both recognize my sound cards but still, I get no sound. Please see:

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Kernel version: 5.11.0-37-generic

Sound cards recognized by the system:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:a170] (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
```

---

Sound cards recognized by ALSA:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:a170] (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
```

---

Sound cards recognized by ALSA, and activated:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:a170] (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
```

Why is it so?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what kernel?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Here's the info you asked me: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, kernel version: 5.11.0-37-generic

Comment: You may want to try the HWE kernel.

Comment: @David I think I have Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) already installed. If I give the following command: hwe-support-status --verbose I get: Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.

Comment: You could try the 5.13 stack

Comment: Do you have any other audio servers running? For example, jack, timidity, Carla, hydrogen, etc ?

Comment: @NateT No, I have not.